# What is a repository in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, centos6, yum

What is a repository in Centos and what does it contain. I I remove all the `.repo` files from the system. What will be its implications. Will it remove the packages as well and will hinder normal operations or will package just not get auto-updated?

Comment: Removing the .repo files : No package installs, no updates. ... »» What is a repository in CentOS ? «« : Please use Google, What is a repository in CentOS https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=what+is+a+repository+in+centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Repositories" are locations where you can download software.

".repo" files are definition files for repositories you might wish to use.

Deleting a .repo file will *not* affect any packages you already have installed - it will just prevent you from updating it (assuming the package in question is available only from that one repository).

You can learn more here:

- https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-maintenance.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps

Answer (score 1):

Repositories in CentOS are collections of software that the server administrator can easily install.

For instance, should you choose to install Firefox, the following command will **query all configured repositories**, and if one of the repos has Firefox then `yum` will download and install it:

```
$ sudo yum install firefox
```

Additionally, you can search for software without installing it:

```
$ yum provides firefox
```

Therefore, repositories (or repos) are online collections of software which `yum` may query and download from.